# How to write a generic method used to return stream using c#

Tags: c#

I am working on an application in which my requirement is to write a generic method that takes a list of data, file names, and types for example **.txt, .csv** files. If the user passes the **.txt** type then it converts the list of data into string JSON and writes it on a text file and returns the stream. If the user passes **.csv** it generates a CSV file and returns that file.

```cs
public enum FileType
{
    Csv = 0,
    Txt
}


private Stream getPartLocatorFileData(IEnumerable<PartDetailInformation> partCatalogDetails, FileType filetype)
{
    var localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    // These are headers properties name like 'Name, LastName, Address etc' 
    localStringBuilder.Append(ApiConstants.PartLocatorFileHeader);

    foreach (var partCatalogDetail in partLocatorFiltered)
    {
        //ManufacturerCode (10)
        localStringBuilder.Append(brandCode.Truncate(10).ToUpperInvariant());

        //PartNumber (30)
        localStringBuilder.Append(partCatalogDetail.PartNumber.Truncate(30));

        //StockQuantity (10)
        localStringBuilder.Append(partCatalogDetail.QuantityAvailable);

        //DealerNumber(20) (We are using company id from agro part website)
        localStringBuilder.Append(dealerIdentity.Truncate(20));

        //Description(100)
        localStringBuilder.Append(partCatalogDetail.Description.Truncate(100));

        //Price(20)
        localStringBuilder.Append(partCatalogDetail.DealerListPrice);
        //Currency(3)
        localStringBuilder.Append(partCatalogDetail.CurrencyCode.Truncate(3));
        localStringBuilder.AppendLine();

    }
    if (filetype == FileType.Csv)
    {
        /// convert stringBuilder to csv     
    }
    else
    {
        /// convert stringBuilder to .txt file 
    }
}
```

Comment: does not seem that Generic method is what you need here unless you write entire system

Comment: What part are you struggling with?  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips to improve your question.

Comment: Define `generic`... generic as in multi-use method or as in C# generics (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do something like this then I don't see how you can just fix it by single generic method

Pseudo code

```cs
public inteface IWriter
{
    void Write(string path, object data);  // -- I don't know format of your data
}

public class CSVWriter : IWriter
{
    public void Write(string path, object data)
    {
        // Convert and write csv here
    }
}

public class TXTWriter : IWriter
{
    public void Write(string path, object data)
    {
        // Convert and write TXT here
    }
}

// -----------------
// and then, if you want generic. in some class

public void Write<T>(string path, object Data) where T : IWriter, new()
{
     T inst = new T();
     inst.Write(path, Data);
}
```

Potentially you can go further and make `data` generic too.